# libGDX: Determination of the direction of touchDragged

Tags: java, math, libgdx

When I write my code inside `touchDragged` method to allow the player dragg with any one of these following directions:

( up, down, right, left, up-right, up-left, down-right, down-left )

[image: 1]]

My code:

```
public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            Image img = img[i][j];
            float imgX = img[i][j].getX();
            float imgY = img[i][j].getY();
            float width = img[i][j].getWidth();
            float height = img[i][j].getHeight();
            if (x > imgX && x <= imgX + width && y > imgY && y <= imgY + height) {
                img.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result: (When the player draggs in `up-right` direction)

[image: 2]]

**But** How can I prevent below squares that contains `X` to listen the touch event? because I know the player want to go this direction `up-right`.

Do I calculate first the slope of straight line [linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form) then according to the slope I determine the direction? or what?

Any Idea ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23731073/how-will-touchdragged-works-in-libgdx

Comment: Haha that is very simple Thanks a lot. So, do I delete my question :) ?

Comment: No, I recommend you keep it here for future users who are also looking for help on this type of question :)