# How to get capture swipe movement on a mobilephone for my game

Tags: java, libgdx, screen, swipe

[Here is my code for movement but with keys , CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkCAe.png)  <---------

I am creating a game but a im very new at coding , i understand some things.
I do not know how to move my "body" of box2d with swipes on the phone.

please help me, there is a link for my code of moving my box2D body but with keys

Comment: Please post your code as text within your question, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully detected swiping in my Android application using this answer. I don't know if it will work in your case. Have a look at it anyway. Have fun

Here is the link: [How to detect the swipe left or Right in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645537/how-to-detect-the-swipe-left-or-right-in-android)

Sorry this one is a more relevant reference: [LibGDX - Get Swipe Up or swipe right etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185799/libgdx-get-swipe-up-or-swipe-right-etc)